# Error in displaying sharedPreferences data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to apply sharedPreferences to save highscore in my android game. I'm just trying this one for me to understand the basic flow of the sharedPreferences. But, unfortunately, I'm having an error in displaying the data. Why I'm having this error?

```
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathattack/com.example.mathattack.Finish}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.example.mathattack.Finish.onCreate(Finish.java:67)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-07 21:06:51.802: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  ... 11 more
```

and this is my `code snippet`:

```
public class Finish extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finish);
        Button okay = (Button) findViewById (R.id.okay);

        Intent svc=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);
        stopService(svc);

        TextView Set1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.time1);       
        TextView totalv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.total);
        TextView nym = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.name);

        long lvl1 = getIntent().getLongExtra("time1", 0L);
        long lvl2 = getIntent().getLongExtra("time2", 0L);      
        long lvl3 = getIntent().getLongExtra("time3", 0L);

        long time1 = lvl1;
        int hours = (int) (time1 / 3600000);
        int minutes1 = (int) (time1 - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
        int seconds1 = (int) (time1 - hours * 3600000 - minutes1 * 60000) / 1000;

        long time2 = lvl2;
        int hours2 = (int) (time1 / 3600000);
        int minutes2 = (int) (time2 - hours2 * 3600000) / 60000;
        int seconds2 = (int) (time2 - hours2 * 3600000 - minutes2 * 60000) / 1000;

        long time3 = lvl3;
        int hours3 = (int) (time3 / 3600000);
        int minutes3 = (int) (time3 - hours3 * 3600000) / 60000;
        int seconds3 = (int) (time3 - hours3 * 3600000 - minutes3 * 60000) / 1000;      

        long total = time1 + time2 + time3;
        int totalH = (int) (total / 3600000);
        int totalMin = (int) (total - totalH * 3600000) / 60000;
        int totalSec = (int) (total - totalH * 3600000 - totalMin * 60000) / 1000;              


        SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putInt("score", totalSec);
        prefsEditor.commit();

        SharedPreferences myPrefs2 = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int highestScore = myPrefs2.getInt("score", 0);



        Set1.setText("Lvl1 Time: " + minutes1 + ":" + seconds1 + "\n" + "Lvl2 Time: " + minutes2 + ":" + seconds2 + "\n" +"Lvl3 Time: " + minutes3+ ":" + seconds3);
        totalv.setText("Total time: " + totalMin + ":" + totalSec);
        nym.setText("Score" + highestScore);
```

Comment: What line is number 67?

Comment: @FoamyGuy it's the `nym.setText("Score" + highestScore);`

Comment: seems like error in your layout, is `TextView` name present, or is it correct in terms of spelling ?

Comment: `nym` must be null then. Make sure that your finish.xml layout file contains a TextView that has the id `name`

Comment: I think, my layout codes is correct. The ids the names. It's all correct. I have a TextView named `name`